# Wait for UI thread to finish

Tags: android, multithreading, android-testing

I am running an instrumentation Activity test.

In that I need to perform some UI operations in one of the UI elements of the Activity.

So I am doing this in the UI thread of the Activity like this:

```
settingsActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        testSwitch.performClick();
    }
});
```

Every time I am hit by `can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` whenever the perform click is called.

A couple of things I have done:

- I have tried putting `Thread.sleep()` after the code but it is not working.
- I am not finishing the activity in the tear down. So, I don't know
  how the Activity is getting destroyed.

Cheers,
Saurav

Comment: As the error says, what you are doing is you are trying to interact with UI element by performing button click, but your activity is probably paused.

Comment: thanks smitalm for responding...but how do i know that the activity is paused ?

Comment: Do some log to find out what is happenning. For exemple log all your activity life cycle  (onCreate, onResume, onStart, onPause, onStop, onDestroy...)

Comment: i checked the stop of the activity is called before the ui element click. I have not finished the activity per say. Does the AcitivtyIntrumentationTest finishes the said activity after some time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just do one thing 
No call for super().
I think its Bug on API Level > 11.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
//No call for super(). Bug on API Level > 11.
}
```

or

If you need to save the instance, and add something to your outState Bundle you can use the following :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
outState.putString("WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_KEY", "WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_VALUE");
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem. Goood luck :)